# How to use the response submitter email address to send an email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-forms

I've a Google form to capture some request details which are stored in associated Google spreadsheet. I've a custom trigger (on_form_submit) which sends email to a number of people whenever a new request is raised. Everything works fine except an issue with email.

My email code is

```
MailApp.sendEmail(_stMainReceiptEmail, _stsubject, message, { 
    cc: _stRequestEmailCC});
```

I shared this form with other users. When they complete the form the request email is always send from my Google mail box.

How can I change this so that the email is send using sender's Google mail.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to send using a different email unless you implement your own oauth flows to save their tokens (asking once each user for approval) and make manual calls to the gmail api. Complex but possible.